# How can I interact with specific Views from the AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, view, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I have a function in my appdelegate that is being called when a notification fires off. When this function is called I am hoping to get access to a specific ViewController and manipulate a table cell whether it is the current View or not.
I was able to get this to work using the rootViewController method but since it is no longer set as the root view this no longer works.

I am currently using this code:

```
let stopOption = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {
        (action:UIAlertAction)->Void in self.audioPlayer?.stop()
        print("Stop index is \(index)")
        Alarms.sharedInstance.setEnabled(false, AtIndex: index)
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC")
        dump(mainVC)
        let cells = (mainVC as! MainAlarmViewController).tableView.visibleCells
        dump(cells)
        for cell in cells
        {
            if cell.tag == index{
                print("Found the cell")
                let sw = cell.accessoryView as! UISwitch
                sw.setOn(false, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }
```

The first "dump" statement is returning the correct ViewController but it does not show any of the subViews and the second dump statement returns "- 0 elements".

Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: You can access viewcontroller. but you can access the sub views only after the main view is loaded.

Comment: What controller is visible by the time the function gets called?

Comment: I should have added that the MainAlarmViewController has loaded by the time this notification arrives and the cells aren't updated whether the MainAlarmViewController is currently visible or not.

Answer (score 1):

When this function is called I am hoping to get access to a specific ViewController and manipulate a table cell whether it is the current View or not

For that you need to use `Notification`

here is example how to use notificatoin http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/notifications-and-userinfo-with-swift-3-0/

you can post notification from `AppDelegate` and catch to `ViewController`